# Как изменить иконку загрузки в приложении?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Прошу простить за столь глупые вопросы, но есть необходимость поменять гифку загрузки. Она показывает загрузку web страницы. Так вот её нужно поменять, но в res её нигде нет

Comment: в assets посмотрите

Comment: @АндроидАндроид , в assets кроме конфиг файла, есть .ttf. Это он?

Comment: ttf это шрифт. По подробнее  можно сформулировать вопрос. С какими инструмантами работаете ?

Comment: @АндрейКасьянов , android studio если вы про это

Comment: У вас же код есть перед глазами, посмотрите по коду на методы, которые показывают гифку, на деяуты в конце концов. Тольок вы можете знать, где она, и как ее поменять. МОжет она вообще загружается из интернета.

Comment: @metalurgus , дело в том что не могу. Использую готовые коды и заменяю только нужны части, при этом большую часть остального не понимаю. Есть он на github https://github.com/gonativeio/gonative-android

Comment: Судя по коду, там не гифка, а обычный прогрессбар (`ProgressBar`).

Comment: @metalurgus , благодарю

Comment: Здесь не принято нецензурно ругаться, даже в своём имени и на иностранном языке. Пожалуйста, смените на что-нибудь более нейтральное.